# Custom controls in Visual Studio Lightswitch

Tags: visual-studio, controls, visual-studio-lightswitch

Can someone point me to an article or tutorial on using custom controls in Visual Studio Lightswitch? I'm trying to add a rich text box to a page, linked to a string property. When running the app, sometimes the field will show up, sometimes it won't. If it does show the width of the field is small, about 2 characters, but will expand when text is pasted inside. Saving doesn't work, though.

I'm not even sure about whether or not I'm allowed to use controls like these in a Lightswitch app, even though custom controls are obviously supported. Are the custom controls restricted to a certain type or set?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

W.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following example, http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/10/LightSwitch-Student-Information-System-Part-3-Custom-Controls.aspx

Also the Training Kit has examples of Custome Controls included.

Answer (score 1):

There is also this tutorial:

Creating A LightSwitch Custom Silverlight Control
http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/2/Creating-A-LightSwitch-Custom-Silverlight-Control.aspx